# android twitter is not returning back to application

Tags: android, twitter

I am devolping an application , with twitter intigration after login to twitter it is not returning to android application.

Please help thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a webview to log the user into twitter, override [onPageFinish](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) in your WebViewClient. Check for when the url shows that they are logged in and then set the WebView visibility to View.GONE.